# one following the other

Tags: adjectives

is it correct to say "one is following the other", when for example referring to cars or persons, or is bad English and I should say "one is following the other one"?

Is there maybe a difference in meaning between both sentences?
Can I use "other"—which I think is an adjective—without "one", like in "other one"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can, but it is not always idiomatic.

I *think* (but I am not certain) that the times when you can are when you have used *one* (or *the first*) before.

So

> One follows the other.

is fine, and so is

> One car is following the other.

But not

> The car is following the other.